# UpdateCommand for Asp GridView using a join between two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview

I have two tables that I join **sims** and **transactionlog** and display in a Asp GridView using a SQLDatasource

Then I have an ASP GridView with the following select and update statements:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM sims s INNER JOIN TransactionLog AS tl ON s.id = tl.SimsId"     
UpdateCommand="UPDATE SET s.Notes=@Notes FROM sims s INNER JOIN TransactionLog AS tl ON s.id = tl.SimsId WHERE s.id=@id and tl.Id=@Id1"
```

Right now I only have the Notes column not set to readonly, but would like to add the others in later as soon as I can get the update statement to work for the notes column first.

When I try to update the notes column the error I'm getting is the following:
**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.]**

Mmm, hope my question is stated clearly enough.

Comment: Gave Mike the credits since he helped me out the most. In the end I just settled for a stored procedure and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you write and SQL `UPDATE` statement with the `FROM` clause.

```
drop table t2
drop table t1
go

create table t1 (
Id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
Name varchar(50) null
)

create table t2 (
t1Id int not null foreign key references t1(id),
Name varchar(50) null
)

insert into t1(name) values('T1Test1')
insert into t1(name) values('T1Test2')
insert into t2(t1Id, name) values(1, 'T2Test1')
insert into t2(t1Id, name) values(2, 'T2Test2')

-- Have a look at the data
select * from t1 inner join t2 on t1.Id = t2.t1Id

update t2 
set t2.Name = 'T2Test1_changed'
from t2 inner join t1 on t2.t1Id = t1.Id
where t1.Id = 1

-- See the changes
select * from t1 inner join t2 on t1.Id = t2.t1Id
```

This means that your statement should look like this:

```
UPDATE sims
SET s.Notes = @Notes 
FROM sims s INNER JOIN TransactionLog tl ON s.id = tl.SimsId 
WHERE s.id = @id and tl.Id = @Id1
```

I do however doubt the `WHERE` clause. Maybe there's no need to use both IDs there, but only you know that.

Try you queries in SQL Management Studio before applying them in you application for a better debugging experience.

Here is the MSDN docs on the `UPDATE` statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

Comment: So if I wanted to update columns on both sides of the join I'm screwed? That doesn't sound right?

Comment: Mike, this article uses an inner join in a update statement just fine. The problem with it and why its not quite right in my case is that it inly updates fields in the "left" table and not both. I tried getting Ben Nadels to work for fields in the left and right table, but cant get it to work. Heres the article: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/938-Using-A-SQL-JOIN-In-A-SQL-UPDATE-Statement-Thanks-John-Eric-.htm

Comment: You are right! You can in face use the `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` statement, but it seems like you only can update one table. I've add an example.

Comment: Yeah, I got the update 1 table part, problem is I need to update both tables in a single update statement :(. Thanks for the stellar effort Mike it has been much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you can enter two statements in the `UpdateCommand` and separate them with a `;`. That should probably work. But there is no way you can update two tables with one `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Mmm haven't tried that but settled in the end to use a StoredProcedure

Comment: Ill give the two update statements a bash when I get some time. If that works Ill mark this answer as correct. Hate having open questions.